# Subnetting to split network into smaller networks

Tags: networking, network-programming, subnet

I've been working on this problem but haven't made much progress.  Could someone help me out?

Your company is assigned the network address 214.56.78.0/24. The company has five work groups to 
support: Administration (11 hosts), Sales (32 hosts), Customer Support (41 hosts), Support servers (8 hosts), 
Web and Database Services (37 hosts). Management would like to provide for 10 percent growth in each 
group. Management would also like to have a “pool” of unused addresses for future use. The corporate 
security group wants you to set the network up such that the five work groups are on different network 
segments. Use subnetting to break the /24 network into smaller networks. List the networks, the netmasks, 
and tell how many IP addresses are “wasted” in your design.

Comment: The original question is off topic, but the answer does a very good job of illustrating variable length subnet masking for those of us looking for a comprehensive example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [VariableLengthSubnetMasking](http://www.orbit-computer-solutions.com/VLSM.php).

1.Start with the subnet for the most users and work your way down.

- Customer Support 41 + 4
- Web and Database Services 37 + 4
- Sales 32 + 3
- Administration 11 + 1
- Support Servers 8 + 1

**Customer Support:** 45 hosts required

```
2^6= 64-2 = 62 usable hosts.
214.56.78.SSNNNNNN -> 2 subnet bits and 6 host bits
Customer Support: 214.56.78.0/26 - 214.56.78.1 - 214.56.78.63
```

**Web and Database Services:** 41 hosts required

```
2^6 = 64-2 = 62 usable hosts
214.56.78.SSNNNNNN -> 2 subnet bits and 6 host bits
Web and Database Services: 214.56.78.64/26 - 214.56.78.64 - 214.56.78.127
```

**Sales:** 35 hosts required

```
2^6 = 64-2 = 62 usable hosts
214.56.78.SSNNNNNN -> 2 subnet bits and 6 host bits
Sales: 214.56.78.128/26 - 214.56.78.128 - 214.56.78.191
```

**Administration:** 12 hosts required

```
2^4 = 16-2 = 14 usable hosts
214.56.78.SSSSNNNN -> 4 subnet bits and 4 host bits
Administration: 214.56.78.192/28 - 214.56.78.192 - 214.56.78.207
```

**Support Servers:** 9 hosts required

```
2^4 = 16-2 = 14 usable hosts
214.56.78.SSSSNNNN -> 4 subnet bits and 4 host bits
Support Servers: 214.56.78.208/28 - 214.56.78.208 - 214.56.78.223
```

**Unused Pool:** what is left

```
2^5= 32 - 2 = 30 usable hosts
214.56.78.SSSNNNNN -> 3 subnet bits and 5 host bits
Unused Pool: 214.56.78.224/27 - 214.56.78.224 - 214.56.78.255
```

**Summary!**

```
Customer Support: 214.56.78.0/26
Web and Database Services: 214.56.78.64/26
Sales: 214.56.78.128/26
Administration: 214.56.78.192/28
Support Servers: 214.56.78.208/28
Unused Pool: 214.56.78.224/27
```